# Popup OnMouseLeave with Keyboard Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I need a suggestion how can I achieve this functionality. I have a popup that has defined Event Triggers for Mouse Leave like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Popup.MouseLeave">
     <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="KeyboardFocusStoryboard">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="False"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

So this event closes the popup ( fade effect ) but I don't want it to close when I have keyboard input and the mouse is not over. After that it would be nice to close the popup when the there is no input ( focus ) from the keyboard anymore.

Any ideas?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe you will approach [LostKeyboardFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.lostkeyboardfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event? In any case, you can be useful for focus this information - [Focus Overview MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx).